Threadpool configuration in Jetty standalone jsr websocket client
When using Jetty 9.4 as standlone jsr websocket client by defualt it created QueuedThreadPool of minimum size 8 and max size 200. Looking at the code for QueuedThreadPool it is not clear if the threadpool size can be configured.
Does anyone have experience configuring that threadpool for jsr websocket client?
All online examples are about configuring QueuedThreadPool when using Jetty server.
